# Killing resurrected monsters

Tags: diablo-iii

A couple questions concerning killing resurrected monsters:

- Do they count towards the massacre bonus?
- Do you get more experience from killing them again?
- Do they drop items/gold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, resurrected monsters don't give you any loot, XP, or bonuses at all. Killing them will keep a Massacre chain alive, but won't increase the bonus you get at the end.

Answer (score 5):

As what Brant said, but it does count towards the max massacre bonus -- just that there is no xp bonus included.

So :

Yes to massacre bonus, but no bonus xp,
No to more experience,
No to loot.